# where do you put the logic for the entire app in swift

Tags: ios, swift, business-logic

I really wondered where to put business logic inside an IOS app..

lets say for example it must check the users location every 5 minutes and
based on that perform a certain action. 
Do you do this in the app delegate or in an other viewcontroller? 
Or in every view controller?

Thanks in advance, im still a beginning programmer.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not dependent on the language or technology used, but it is a general problem on how to divide application's responsibilities in order to achieve low coupling between different components. So  there is not a correct and absolute answer! Maybe the right answer is "it depends". When you're linking  this logic to the technology think about what the components that you mentioned are there for. App delegate and view controllers should not do much work. Application delegate responsibility is to manage the application status and view controllers to manage views. So they should delegate other responsibility to other components. But in reality if your application in not so big and you don't care about modifiability and cohesion you are free to place logic wherever you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i understand. but will every code run itself even when the view is not on the foreground in the app? lets say for example: user puts in a city name in one view(Screen A), he then goes to another view(Screen C). But then the app has to check based on the city's name the weather and show another screen(screen B) if the temperature hits a certain level. Where would you put this kind of logic? in Screen B, or in all the screens so it does not matter which screen is on the foreground, it will always execute the same code?